# Getting a collection of pages with refinerycms

Tags: layout, refinerycms

I've been customising refinerycms with my limited knowledge of ruby/rails, and I've come across a problem:

After changing the application.html.erb to my preferred look, I have removed

```
<%= yield %>
```

And replaced it with

```
<%= @page.content_for(:body).html_safe %>
```

Now in my application.html.erb, I have a navigation menu. I'd like to get a list of contructed pages and parse them into the menu, ie Home, About Us, Contact Us etc...

Comment: Personally I wouldn't remove the yield, it's required to display any template content in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer, I put the <% yield %> back in the application.html.erb file.

Then I accessed the list of pages by using

```
<% @Pages = Page.in_menu %>
<% @Pages.in_menu.each do |p| %>
  <li><a>p.title</a></li>
<%end%>
```

Still not sure how to generate a link href though, it works if you do /p.title, but if you have a space in the title it breaks, I'll update the answer when I find it.

@parndt: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction on IRC